# How to add count of different query using a query in mysql5?

Tags: php, mysql, performance, mysql5

Hi I need a query like this

```
    select count(id) from employee where.. => gives count1=10

    select count(id) from emplyer where..  => gives count2=5

    select count(id) from users where..    => gives count3=20
```

I can add these result like this

```
    count = count1+count2+count3;
```

But I want to know whether there is any option get count using a single query  instead of add these result separatly. Also I want to know which one is the best way in case of application perfomance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do

```
SELECT ((select count(id) from employee where..) + (select count(id) from emplyer where..) + (select count(id) from users where..))
```

There will hardly be a performance difference - adding three integers is neither a challenge for the MySql nor for the php engine.

Comment: Excuse me.. there is not only addition but also there is more than three queries for getting that count value Those are not simple fetch queries. So I ask about performance

Answer (score 0):

If you use group by clause you can add option WITH ROLLUP which will return total sum of all counts in group. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html